# Popover component hiding behind the table cells of Iron data table in polymer

Tags: polymer, z-index, iron-data-table

[popover overriding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIn1l.png)

[Date picker overriding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDIx1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Well, bad news is that it's `iron-list` issue (namely `iron-list` using `z-translation`).

Good news is that there is kind of a workaround for that... I had the same problem and what I ended up with was a behavior (but you can make put this in your component) that has something like:

```
tableListOverflowVisible: function (...tables) {
        tables.forEach((id) => {
          if (typeof id !== 'string') {
            return;
          }

          const table = this.$[id];

          if (!table) {
            return;
          }

          Polymer
            .dom(table)
            .node.querySelector('iron-list')
            .setAttribute('style', 'overflow: visible !important;');
        });
      },
```

Just pass your table id there and that should do the job...

Comment: Thanks. I will try that

Answer (score 0):

If your z-index is properly set, check the background-color, it may be set to transparent.

Comment: Only the issue happen when the popover position at bottom.

Comment: Are you setting ```z-index``` with the ```:host``` selector?

Comment: z-index is already there. But its not taking. Table column property over riding that. Some flex property increment the value.

Comment: Yes. Table row and column are flex property. I think that flex property overwriting some properties.

Comment: Sorry, not much else I can do to try to help without you providing some code along these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve