# Popover and date time picker components hiding behind the iron-list of iron-data-table in Polymer

Tags: polymer, flexbox, web-component, iron-data-table, iron-list

When I click on a component inside the 5th row, component not hided by 1,2,3 and 4 rows. Only hide the component by rows after 5th one(6,7,8..)

Some flex property affecting in the component style.

[Working fine in this state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzS5X.png)

[Data behind the table list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGqJy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Common problem in that component, already answered that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43721997/722462). I also used calendar in that list and this solution worked for me.